# Condition for $\langle m\rangle\subseteq\langle n\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assuming $m,n\in{\mathbb{Z}}$, what is the necessary and sufficient condition such that the question at hand is valid?

If $\langle m\rangle=\{m^a|a\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\langle n\rangle=\{n^b|b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, then for $x\in{\langle m\rangle}$ I need to show that $x\in{\langle n\rangle}$.  If $x=m^a$, in order that it is in $\langle n\rangle$, it must be able to be written as $n^b$.  So does this imply that $m=n^c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$?  Is that the condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making things harder to yourself writing the operation multiplicatively and not, as usual, additively (after all, $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is a group under *addition*, **not** under multiplication or exponentiation):

$$\forall\,m\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\langle m\rangle:=\{km\;;\;k\in\Bbb Z\}$$

Grasping the above, we now have that

$$\langle m\rangle \le\langle n\rangle\iff \forall\,k\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;km\in\langle n\rangle\iff km\;\text{is a multiple of}\;n\iff n\mid m$$

Comment: Yup.  You're right.  Thanks!  Isn't it true that $m^a=ma$ if the binary operation is addition?  I see that using that notation can cloud your view...

Comment: Using the notation $\;m^a\;$ to mean $\;ma\;$ is particularly confusing when both operations (exponentiation and multiplication) *exist* in the given set, as in this case...and what's the use?

Comment: I've seen that use as a general case for dealing with groups when no operation is defined explicitly, but I suppose the choice of $\mathbb{Z}$ makes it more logical to use $ma$ instead of $m^a$.  thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

To contain is to divide, so $\langle m\rangle \subseteq \langle n\rangle $, if and only if $n\mid m$.

Comment: Thanks @dietrich.  So it doesn't just have to be powers, just divisible?

Comment: We have $\langle m\rangle=m\mathbb{Z}$, if we write additively. You wrote powers for this.